# How to report pirated textbooks on Academia.edu?

Tags: copyright, social-media

I received a notification today from Academia.edu of a recently-uploaded "paper" that was similar to one I previously downloaded.  On clicking through, the "paper" turned out to be a PDF of a pirated textbook.  (Just to be clear:  the account that posted the PDF was *not* the author.)  Is there a way to report this?  The info at http://support.academia.edu/customer/en/portal/articles/1734342-reporting-a-fake-offensive-or-spam-profile explains how to report a "Fake, Offensive, or Spam profile", but that doesn't seem to exactly describe this situation.

I know Academia.org is a problematic site in many ways, but this is the first time I've seen it cross into LibGen territory.

Comment: You will have to check their website and perhaps use some contact info. We are not linked to them... You could also inform the publisher of the book - they may be **very** interested... and prepared to take action...

Comment: @SolarMike Oh, I know this site and that one have no connection.  But there is probably some overlap in userbase.

Comment: Only by a blinkered few...

Answer (score 3):

I would contact the textbook publisher. As noted by [Solar Mike](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/72855/solar-mike) in a comment, they would care about the problem and have time and resources to do something about it. Part of the publisher's job is to protect their work.

Comment: And the publisher can make use of Academia.edu's [copyright policy](https://www.academia.edu/copyright).

Comment: @Anyon Exactly.